# sed swallows whitespaces while inserting content

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to insert a new line before the first match with `sed`. The content that I wanna insert starts with spaces but `sed` or `bash` swallows the whitespaces.

**hello.txt**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

**The content to insert in my case coming from a variable this way:**

```
content="   hello"
```

**The command that I have created:**

```
sed -i "/line 2/i $content" hello.txt
```

**Result:**

```
line 1
hello
line 2
line 3
```

**Expected result:**

```
line 1
   hello
line 2
line 3
```

It seems that bash swallows the whitespaces. I have tried to use quotes around the variable this way: `sed -i "/line 2/i \"$content\""` but unfortunately it does not work. After playing with this for 2 hours I just decided that I ask help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how GNU sed works, yes - any whitespace between the command `i` and the start of text is eaten. You can add a backslash (At least, in GNU sed; haven't tested others) to keep the spaces:

```sh
$ sed "/line 2/i \\$content" hello.txt
line 1
   hello
line 2
line 3
```

POSIX sed `i` always requires a backslash after the `i` and then a newline with the text to insert on the next line (And to insert multiple lines, a backslash at the end of all but the last), instead of the one-line version that's a GNU extension.

```sh
sed "/line 2/i\\
$content
" hello.txt
```

I don't have a non-GNU version handy to test, so I don't know if the leading whitespace in the variable will be eaten, but I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a backslash instead:

```
content="\    hello"
```

Otherwise, it's viewed as part of the separated between the `/i` and the `hello`.

Note also that the `$content` variable could end up including all sorts of characters that `sed` would interpret differently... so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

[ed](/questions/tagged/ed) would work well here:

```sh
ed hello.txt <<END_ED
/line 2/i
$content
.
wq
END_ED
```